# How to make an installer for your electron app

Tags: javascript, json, electron, electron-builder, electron-forge

So I'm trying to make an installer from the end of this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TnXz_nnQZrw for my electron app but I get an error and it doesn't help me at all

Here is my package.json

```json
{
    "name": "second-electron-attempt",
    "productName": "CPU Monitoring",
    "version": "1.0.2",
    "description": "A great cpu monitoring tool",
    "main": "src/index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "electron-forge start",
        "package": "electron-forge package",
        "make": "electron-forge make",
        "publish": "electron-forge publish",
        "lint": "echo \"No linting configured\"",
        "build-installer": "electron-builder"
    },
    "build": {
        "appId": "com.nickos.app",
        "win": {
            "target": "NSIS",
            "icon": "src/fraggaros.png",
            "requestedExecutionLevel": "requireAdministrator"
        },
        "nsis": {
            "installerIcon": "src/fraggaros.png",
            "uninstallerIcon": "src/fraggaros.png",
            "uninstallDisplayName": "CPU Monitor",
            "license": "license.txt",
            "oneClick": false,
            "allowToChangeInstallationDirectory": true
        }
    },
    "keywords": [],
    "author": {
        "name": "NickVelos420",
        "email": "velosn@gmail.com"
    },
    "license": "MIT",
    "config": {
        "forge": {
            "packagerConfig": {},
            "makers": [
                {
                    "name": "@electron-forge/maker-squirrel",
                    "config": {
                        "name": "second_electron_attempt"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "name": "@electron-forge/maker-zip",
                    "platforms": [
                        "darwin"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "@electron-forge/maker-deb",
                    "config": {}
                },
                {
                    "name": "@electron-forge/maker-rpm",
                    "config": {}
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "electron-squirrel-startup": "^1.0.0",
        "os-utils": "0.0.14"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@electron-forge/cli": "^6.0.0-beta.54",
        "@electron-forge/maker-deb": "^6.0.0-beta.54",
        "@electron-forge/maker-rpm": "^6.0.0-beta.54",
        "@electron-forge/maker-squirrel": "^6.0.0-beta.54",
        "@electron-forge/maker-zip": "^6.0.0-beta.54",
        "electron": "12.0.2",
        "electron-builder": "^22.10.5"
    }
}
```

And this is the error

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! second-electron-attempt@1.0.2 build-installer: `electron-builder`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the second-electron-attempt@1.0.2 build-installer script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

It says that there is additional logging above but this is what is above
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ruXXC.png

If anyone knows please answer with some code or a great tutorial. btw I've searched on google but there is nothing that tells you how to make an installer for electron. Thank you!

Comment: That screenshot doesn't even help a bit. Please [edit] your question to include *the full stacktrace* ("error logging") as there might be some valuable information hiding in there.